# Build menu based in Vocabulary (Taxonomy)?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I just follow this [tutorial](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-add-block-menu-tags-or-other-taxonomy-terms-drupal-site) to build a **menu** based in the **tags** vocabulary. Everything is fine but now if I add a new term in **admin/structure/taxonomy/tags/list** the menu doesn't update, I mean that the new added term doesn't show up.

The problem is that I can't find to check: **Synchronises change to this vocabulary** because 
I don't have this option in **admin/structure/taxonomy/tags/edit** as showed in the tutorial. Maybe this is because I'm using D7 and the tutorial is for D6? Where are these options in D7?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the development snapshot for Drupal 7. The update is available in that version.